# How to save a TIFF image format CMYK with Alpha channel in C#

Tags: c#, cmyk

I'm developing an application that loads a TIFF image, concatenate it with another image I created in runtime and save the concatenated one without changing format of the original TIFF.

I'm able to do that using TiffBitmapEncoder & TiffBitmapDecoder + BitmapSource.CopyPixels - **With CMYK tiff images only**

A special case is **TIFF CMYK with an additional Alpha channel** (yes, it's 40bits depth), and I'm stuck.
I need to use TiffBitmapDecoder to save the file after modification, but I can only specify format PixelFormats.Cmyk32 for it, and that is not the correct format in case having Alpha channel.
The original format wasn't recognizable by TiffBitmapEncoder fyi..

What can I do/try here to achieve my purpose?

Comment: Duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068801/wpf-bitmapimage-and-tiff-with-cmyk-alpha & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48929763/save-tiff-with-transparency-alpha-channel

Comment: Also this article: https://www.graphicsmill.com/docs/gm5/WorkingwithTIFFExtraChannels.htm

Comment: I tried to evaluate graphics mill API using trial license. Unluckily, it doesn't work with desktop application.